# Python. Как найти индексы всех чисел в строке

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть строка `"123 _457 78"`, нужно, чтобы код вывел индекс каждого числа (начало и конец). Вывод для этой строки должен быть: [[0, 2], [5, 7], [9, 10]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя regexp это делается в одну строчку.

```
import re
result = list(map(lambda m: [m.start(), m.end()-1], re.finditer(r'\d+', "123 _457 78")))
print(result)
```